# Calculate $x$ from a given ratio calculation with a known answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

I have the below ratio calculation, and I need to find the value of $x$:

$ \dfrac{181.5 + 16.5x}{181.5 + 11x} = 1.251 $

Can I use this to find the value of $x$?

Let me know if I need to provide more info.

Cheers

Comment: To be clear... are you saying that the ratio of $181.5 + 16.5X$ compared to $181.5+11X$ is the same as the ratio of $1.251$ to $1$?, or equivalently that $\dfrac{181.5+16.5X}{181.5+11X}=1.251$?  Or are you saying that the sum of $181.5$ and $11X$ and $\frac{16.5X}{181.5}$ is $1.251$, or in other words $181.5+\frac{16.5X}{181.5}+11X=1.251$?  Or are you saying something else entirely?  Regardless... I can't imagine whatever you are interested in is anything more than a simple linear equation in $X$ for which middle-school level algebra is plenty to solve for $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant $(181.5+16.5X)/(181.5+11X)=1.251$, we have

$181.5+16.5X=1.251(181.5+11X)$;

$(16.5-1.251\times11)X=2.739X=181.5(0.251)$;

$X\approx 16.6325$.

Comment: Note:  OP originally said $181.5+16.5X/181.5+11X=1.251$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

From $$\frac{181.5+16.5x}{181.5+11x}=1.251$$

Multiply both sides by $181.5+11x$, we have

$$181.5+16.5x = 1.251(181.5+11x)$$

Now, this is just a linear equation in $x$, try to solve it by isolating $x$.